# How to change the data of firebase with click in firebase recycler adapter?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to change the data of firebase if someone clicks on it. There are 10 users in my app and each user have a showGigCount node. How can I change this data if someone clicks on it. i.e if showGigCount of User "Quikig" is 1 and someone clicks on it then the value will be changed 0. I have tried the below code but it only change the value of current online user. Really appreciate your help. Thank You

**MyViewHolder class**

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView geglink, userName, userAbout;
    URLEmbeddedView previewLink;
    View v;
public MyViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        previewLink =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.uev);
        geglink = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcvGigLink);
        userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcvName);
        userAbout = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcvAbout);
        v = itemView;
    }
```

**DashboardActivity**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelClass> options;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, MyViewHolder> adapter;
    DatabaseReference dRef;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    int remainingClicks;
    int showGigCount;
    int showGigCount1;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    String UID;
    TextView clicks, zeroClicks, userName;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        clicks = findViewById(R.id.clicks);
        zeroClicks = findViewById(R.id.zeroClicks);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.userName);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        }

            dRef.child(UID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    remainingClicks = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(snapshot.child("clicksRemain").getValue()));
                    showGigCount =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(snapshot.child("showGigCount").getValue()));
                    String username =  String.valueOf(snapshot.child("name").getValue());
                    clicks.setText(String.valueOf(remainingClicks));
                    userName.setText(username);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dashboardRCV);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
      LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        // This will display the data of a user if his showGigCount is greater than 0.
        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("Users");
        Query queryByShowGigCount = usersRef.orderByChild("showGigCount").startAt(1);
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelClass>()
                .setQuery(queryByShowGigCount, ModelClass.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, MyViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ModelClass model) {

                holder.previewLink.setURL(model.getGig(), new URLEmbeddedView.OnLoadURLListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadURLCompleted(URLEmbeddedData data) {

                        holder.previewLink.title(data.getTitle());
                        holder.previewLink.description(data.getDescription());
                        holder.previewLink.host(data.getHost());
                        holder.previewLink.thumbnail(data.getThumbnailURL());
                        holder.previewLink.favor(data.getFavorURL());
                    }
                });

                    holder.previewLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            if (UID != null){
                                if (remainingClicks >= 1) {
                                    remainingClicks--;
                                    showGigCount ++;
                                    clicks.setText(String.valueOf(remainingClicks));
                                    UserClicksCounts();
                                    UserShowGigCounts();
//                                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(model.getGig()));
//                                startActivity(browserIntent);
                                } else if (remainingClicks == 0){
                                    zeroClicks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                            String user_clicked = getRef(position).getKey();
                            dRef.child(user_clicked).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                    showGigCount1 =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(snapshot.child("showGigCount").getValue()));
                                    showGigCount1--;
                                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(UID);
                                    myRef.child("showGigCount").setValue(showGigCount1);

                                    //  Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, ""+user_clicked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                }
                            });


                        }
                    });
            }
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    void UserClicksCounts(){
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(UID);
        myRef.child("clicksRemain").setValue(remainingClicks);
    }
// This will count how many times the gig will be shown to the user
    void UserShowGigCounts(){
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(UID);
        myRef.child("showGigCount").setValue(showGigCount);
    }
}
```

[image: Database]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo this code only change the data of current online user, not for all users.

Comment: So isn't what you want? Do you need to change the value of showGigCount to all users? If yes, what is the new value?

Comment: @AlexMamo Let suppose there are 10 users and if  user A click on user B data the showGigCount of user A should be incremented by 1 and showGigCount of user B will be decreased by 1. Let me know if it make any sense

Comment: I see now but it's a little more complex than I can reasonably answer, here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @AlexMamo where can you answer this?

Comment: It is definitely too broad to reasonably answer here in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AlexMamo can you mention on which platform or any other medium can you answer this question?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other platform.